# Error Status 500 Source not be null struts2 fileupload not working

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts2, struts, javabeans

simply i want to upload file to database and string of text fields
i want this if user not select any file then only string of textfield will save in database. and some default filename will save in column of fileuploader.

here is my codding

```
jsp code

<form class="login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="department">
            <p class="lead">Add Department</p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="depname" class="required form-control" placeholder="Department Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="file" name="userImage" label="Choose File" size="40">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg1 btn-block" name="submit" value="Add">
            </div>
                    <s:actionmessage />
                    <s:actionerror />
               </form>
```

action class department.java

```
package myweb;




import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import static org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext.getServletContext;

public class department extends ActionSupport {

    private File userImage;
    private String userImageContentType;
    private String userImageFileName;
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public File getUserImage() {
        return userImage;
    }

    public void setUserImage(File userImage) {
        this.userImage = userImage;
    }

    public String getUserImageContentType() {
        return userImageContentType;
    }

    public void setUserImageContentType(String userImageContentType) {
        this.userImageContentType = userImageContentType;
    }

    public String getUserImageFileName() {
        return userImageFileName;
    }

    public void setUserImageFileName(String userImageFileName) {
        this.userImageFileName = userImageFileName;
    }

    public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
        return servletRequest;
    }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
    }




    private String depname;




    public String getDepname() {
        return depname;
    }

    public void setDepname(String depname) {
        this.depname = depname;
    }



    @Override
        public String execute() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
        {
            HttpServletRequest request = null;


            String path=getServletContext().getInitParameter("path");
            String place=getServletContext().getInitParameter("place");
            String uname=getServletContext().getInitParameter("uname");
            String pass=getServletContext().getInitParameter("pass");

            try
            {
                String filename=new java.util.Date().getTime()+getUserImageFileName();
                String filePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"pics\\";
                File fileToCreate = new File(filePath,  filename);
                FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
                if(!userImage.exists())
                {
                    filename="default.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection myconn = DriverManager.getConnection(path+place, uname, pass);
                    try

                    {
                        if(getUserImageContentType().equals("image/gif") || getUserImageContentType().equals("image/jpeg") || getUserImageContentType().equals("image/png"))
                        {
                            String query="insert into department(depname,depimage) values(?,?)";
                            PreparedStatement myst=myconn.prepareStatement(query);
                            myst.setString(1, getDepname());
                            myst.setString(2, filename);
                            if(myst.executeUpdate()>0)
                            {
                                addActionMessage("Department Added");
                                return "save";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                addActionError("Error in Something");
                                return "error";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            addActionError("Only Image File Is Supported");
                            return "notsupported";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(SQLException e)
                    {
                        addActionError("Error Due to "+e.getMessage());
                        return "error2";
                    }
                }

            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                addActionError("Error In Connection Due to "+e.getMessage());
                return "conn_error";
            }

        return null;


        }

}
```

i tried many codes to fix this problem not not succeed

```
struts.xml




<action name="department" class="myweb.department">
               <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
                <param name="allowedTypes">image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="save">add_department.jsp</result>
                        <result name="error">add_department.jsp</result>
                        <result name="error2">add_department.jsp</result>
                        <result name="conn_error">add_department.jsp</result>
                        <result name="notsupported">add_department.jsp</result>
        </action>



error logs
```

this is the error logs that I am facing

```
22988 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Unable to find 'struts.multipart.saveDir' property setting. Defaulting to javax.servlet.context.tempdir
23499 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] ERROR org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Exception occurred during processing request: Source must not be null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Source must not be null
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:761)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:731)
    at myweb.department.execute(department.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:325)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:325)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1156)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: If you got the HTTP 500 error, you can also get an error log to find out the cause. Please check the log and add it to your question.

Comment: i have attached the error logs please check and give me the solution

Comment: Please show your JSP file.

Comment: jsp code uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Try using Struts2 taglib in your JSP, for example, `<s:form>`, `<s:file>`,,, and so on.

I think [this page](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-file-upload-save-tutorial-with-example/) helps you. Please read carefully.